# get tax rate percentage for each product in Woocommerce order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I got two things to ask:
The first one is I want to get tax rate percentage of each item on an order in woocommerce through this code:

```
   $items = $order->get_items();
    if ($items) foreach ($items as $item_key => $item_value) {
        $_tax = new WC_Tax();
        $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item_value );
        $product_tax_class = $_product->get_tax_class();
        $tax =  $_tax->get_rates($product_tax_class);
```

The result is blank so I don't know what is wrong with the code.

Second, standard rate always shows as blank task class. It might be confused with none tax product. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: on which hook your are trying this code?

Comment: If you look into the DB, the "Standard vat" has an empty `tax_class_rate`. That's why it's "blank"

Answer (score 8):

Don't know if its still useful for you but it might be for others.

```
   //Get items/products from order
   $items = $order->get_items();
   $tax = new WC_Tax();
   //Loop through each item
   foreach($items as $item){
       //Get product by supplying variation id or product_id
       $_product = get_product( $item['variation_id'] ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'] );
       //Get rates of the product
       $taxes = $tax->get_rates($wc_product->get_tax_class());
       $rates = array_shift($taxes);
       //Take only the item rate and round it. 
       $item_rate = round(array_shift($rates));
   }
```

Comment: It is also worth to note that if you are using "Standard tax rate" tax class will be empty.

Comment: Add $tax = new WC_Tax(); before the for loop. And correct the variable name $_product with $wc_product in line 6, because it's used as such in line 8.